# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_SSLv2_ ..."

Tags: c++, openssl, ld, telegram-bot

I am trying to build a small example for a Telegram Bot library in C++ (https://github.com/reo7sp/tgbot-cpp#samples) but when linking I get this output:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SSLv2_client_method", referenced from:
      boost::asio::ssl::context::context(boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method) in libTgBot.a(HttpClient.cpp.o)
  "_SSLv2_method", referenced from:
      boost::asio::ssl::context::context(boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method) in libTgBot.a(HttpClient.cpp.o)
  "_SSLv2_server_method", referenced from:
      boost::asio::ssl::context::context(boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method) in libTgBot.a(HttpClient.cpp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

using this command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -l boost_system -l boost_iostreams -l boost_unit_test_framework -l boost_exception -l TgBot -l pthread -l ssl -l crypto -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

I have openssl 1.0.2 installed: do I have to get a 2.x version? I can't find it with homebrew (my system is OSX 10.9.5)... sorry for the newbie question.

Comment: The code you're building appears to use the obsolete SSL2 protocol. Checking openssl 1.0.2g on Linux, it does appear to still include the relevant API functions. Perhaps your port of openssl removed all support for the obsoleted SSL2 protocol, completely, like what OpenBSD did.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I just installed openssl 1.0.2g from openssl.org but I get the same output as before (of course, I changed the include path with bot -L and -I options). Do you think I have to enable SSL2 when configuring openssl? (I googled around but I can't find how to enable it).

Answer (score 1):

1. `brew install openssl`
2. open `~/.bash_profile`
3. add

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

4. source ~/.bash_profile