# boost::asio::ssl::context::context(boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method) undefined Symbols

Tags: c++, macos, ssl, boost

I am running OSX Yosemite 10.10.5 with clang-700.0.72 and a brew installed boost 1.56.

I am using boost::asio for non-ssl and tls sockets.
The offending lines are **not** in my project, but appear to originate from boost 1.56 itself.

I use cmake, and I do link with openssl, using `find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)` and I do have `openssl 1.0.2g`.

The project uses C++11, and the offending lines appear to be:

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SSLv2_client_method", referenced from:
      boost::asio::ssl::context::context(boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method) in asio_tls.cpp.o
  "_SSLv2_method", referenced from:
      boost::asio::ssl::context::context(boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method) in asio_tls.cpp.o
  "_SSLv2_server_method", referenced from:
      boost::asio::ssl::context::context(boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method) in asio_tls.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

**I do NOT use** SSLv2 at all, in fact the code focuses on using only TLS v2:

```
class asio_socket_https
{
public:
    asio_socket_https(const std::string token)
    : ctx_(boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv12_client), token_(token)
    {}
```

Later on, when intialising the socket and context, I do:

```
ctx_.set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds
                |boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2
                |boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv3
                |boost::asio::ssl::context::no_tlsv1
                |boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
```

I have no compilation errors, the application is linked against libssl/libcrypto, and I have not tested it under Linux (only OSX).

I've seen an SO question with the same topic but no answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200065/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-sslv2).

Actual link flags:

`/usr/bin/g++   -std=c++11 -Wall -g -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names   CMakeFiles/asio_tls.dir/examples/asio_tls.cpp.o  -o asio_tls  librapp.0.2.dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_random-mt.dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework-mt.dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2g/lib/libssl.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2g/lib/libcrypto.dylib`

## EDIT

I tested the same code today under Ubuntu 14.04 and it built fine (with no issues at all) when detecting openssl 1.0.1f.
This is starting to seem like an OSX-specific issue.

@rhashimoto appears to be right, whereas the linker is using the Cellar version of openssl in `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/` the headers used are under `/usr/local/openssl` which I don't think is the same managed by brew.

## SOLUTION

The problem was in my `CMakeLists.txt` I had assumed that `find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)` would be enough, unfortunatelly what this did was break the version of library linking with the library headers imported.

The *default* library was OSX's openssl, whereas I was linking explicitly with `${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}`.

Simply adding the following fixed the issue (now it uses openssl installed from **brew**):

```
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
if (OPENSSL_FOUND)
    include_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()
```

And then do a `target_link_libraries(... ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})`

Comment: check the order of link arguments (libraries go _after_ your own objects)

Comment: @sehe thanks, the order is correct, I've added an edit of the link flags (cmake verbose). It appears that I am missing the specific openssl functions only - as the rest of the openssl links properly. I think this is localised to OSX, but I haven't got access to Linux ATM.

Comment: I would verify whether the OpenSSL headers you're compiling against are the ones for the OpenSSL library you're linking with. You could try injecting a `-H` flag into your compiler options to find out.

Comment: @rhashimoto I think that probably boost 1.56 is referring to deprecated functions. At first I thought I was linking vs the apple libcrypto, but the output above uses the brew installed openssl. I'm not including the headers in cmake, so this might imply that it uses other headers? However the cmake find_package does point to openssl 1.0.2g. I will however try your suggestion and see whats the output, many thanks!

Comment: @rhashimoto you are correct, different headers and libraries! If you want, add an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost Asio does use `SSLv2_client_method()` and `SSLv2_server_method()` in [`boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp`](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/develop/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp#L74), conditional on the absence of the preprocessor symbol `OPENSSL_NO_SSL2`:

```
#if defined(OPENSSL_NO_SSL2)
  case context::sslv2:
  case context::sslv2_client:
  case context::sslv2_server:
    boost::asio::detail::throw_error(
        boost::asio::error::invalid_argument, "context");
    break;
#else // defined(OPENSSL_NO_SSL2)
  case context::sslv2:
    handle_ = ::SSL_CTX_new(::SSLv2_method());
    break;
  case context::sslv2_client:
    handle_ = ::SSL_CTX_new(::SSLv2_client_method());
    break;
  case context::sslv2_server:
    handle_ = ::SSL_CTX_new(::SSLv2_server_method());
    break;
#endif // defined(OPENSSL_NO_SSL2)
```

`OPENSSL_NO_SSL2` should be defined in your OpenSSL library headers if it does not include support for SSLv2, but apparently your build is not picking it up.

One common explanation for this kind of behavior is that you are compiling with headers from one OpenSSL library that still supports SSLv2 and linking with binaries from another OpenSSL library that does not support SSLv2. It may be helpful to insert the `-H` flag into your compiler options, which will log the headers paths as they are processed, as you can then verify which headers are being used.

Comment: Thanks for the help, your suggestion of using `-H` is what pin-pointed the problem with the different library/headers being picked up by cmake.